# How to avoid gaps in the instantiating of ground tiles of an endless runner game with a moving world in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to get the sidewalk that my player runs on to repeat in a endless runner style game. Instead of the player moving, it is the world around it that moves. This is causing some troubles when trying to instantiate more of the sidewalk. The script I'm using instantiates the next tile once the "Player" exits the trigger around the tile. Or, in this case, when the tile passes under the player on the X axis.

With the tiles moving instead of the player this causes gaps in the tiling as the tile waits for the player to exit its trigger.

here are the scripts I'm using.

To Spawn the tiles

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SidewalkTileSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject sidewalkTile;

    Vector3 nextSpawPoint;

    public void SpawnSidewalk()
    {
        GameObject temp = Instantiate(sidewalkTile, nextSpawPoint, Quaternion.identity);
        nextSpawPoint = temp.transform.GetChild(1).transform.position;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            SpawnSidewalk();
        }
        
    }
}
```

a simple move transform to move the tile

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SimpleMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

and the trigger

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TileTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{

    SidewalkTileSpawner sidewalkTileSpawner;

    private const string tagPlayer = "Player";

    void Start()
    {
        sidewalkTileSpawner = FindObjectOfType<SidewalkTileSpawner>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
         if(other.gameObject.tag == tagPlayer)
        {
            sidewalkTileSpawner.SpawnSidewalk();
            Destroy(gameObject, 7);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

I'm thinking maybe since I'm moving the tiles and not the player, the spawner is spawning the next tile where the "nextSpawnPoint" was and not currently is.

To try and fix this I tried to subtract the X value as it was spawning to line up the tiles, but this created an effect that eventually either stacked on top of each other, or slowly made the gap bigger.

here is the script for the spawn

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SidewalkTileSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject sidewalkTile;

    Vector3 nextSpawPoint;

    public void SpawnSidewalk()
    {
        GameObject temp = Instantiate(sidewalkTile, nextSpawPoint, Quaternion.identity);
        nextSpawPoint = temp.transform.GetChild(1).transform.position;
    }

    public void SpawnSidewalkTile()
    {
        GameObject temp = Instantiate(sidewalkTile, nextSpawPoint - new Vector3(1.8f, 0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
        nextSpawPoint = temp.transform.GetChild(1).transform.position;
    }


    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            SpawnSidewalk();
        }
        
    }
}
```

and the trigger

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TileTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{

    SidewalkTileSpawner sidewalkTileSpawner;

    private const string tagPlayer = "Player";

    void Start()
    {
        sidewalkTileSpawner = FindObjectOfType<SidewalkTileSpawner>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
         if(other.gameObject.tag == tagPlayer)
        {
            sidewalkTileSpawner.SpawnSidewalkTile();
            Destroy(gameObject, 7);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

I can work out exactly why you've got the gap but can't explain very easily so here is the 2 solutions I can think of:

1. I would pass the old tile's transform into the `SpawnSidewalk()` so it looks like `SpawnSidwalk(Transform old)` and then add the length of a tile onto the position of the old tile to get the spawn point for the new tile. I think something like `Vector3 SpawnPiont = new Vector3(old.position.x + tileWidth, 0,0)`. That assumes it spawns at 0,0,0 and moves in the negative direction to start off with. If not just add the actual spawn point to everything and/or swap + for - retrospectively
2. Make sure the rigidbody for the tile trigger is in the right place. This is possibly easier but less robust. If the gap is the same every time, you can just move end of the trigger box and the gap should change size.

Hope this helped